# Is Code For Hybrid Apps Installed On The App Or Hosted?

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am looking at the best approach to take to build an App for a startup. Basically the app will use limited native functionality apart from GEO and Camera features. Now traditionally I have always built apps using native objective-c but the owner of the startup is looking to streamline both IOS and Android development by building a Hybrid app.

I have been looking at the Ionic framework but I have a question. Is the Ionic framework hosted remotely and called via a UIWebView or is it installed on within the app itself?

Obviously one the benefits we were hoping for was the ability to update the app on the fly without having to submit a new build each time for review.

The app will also interact with our PHP platform via JSON so I can't really see an issue there.

Just looking for some advice from more experienced hybrid developers.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/updating-ionic-apps-on-the-fly/1577/10), seems that someone ve already tried to achieve this. Anyway ionic provide a service that can build your project for both ios and Android, so you can install the entire app on your device and make only http call outside or make a basic WebView that ask for content to a remote host.

Comment: The app is installed with all the html, css and javascript (and other assets). In other words, it does not have to request them (templates, scripts, etc...) from a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hybrid mobile apps are like any other apps **installed** on your device.

They are built with a combination of web technologies and hosted inside a native application that utilizes a mobile platform’s (WebView).

For updating you need to submit your build to review before you publish it to the store ( the only official way to install apps in devices ).

You api or backend can be in php or .net  or .. when it can deliver information via json and http calls to your app.

Hope that's help